God is the alpha and omega. Why did God create man when he knew man would fail?
God being the Alpha and Omega, exists outside of his creation and sees the past, present and the future. I believe God created man knowing man would fail. The Creation itself demonstrated two of the most important aspects of God. What are these two aspects?

I think you meant fall, it happened as part of His grand plan. People learn best from mistakes, so did Adam and Eve.

This question has been asked, over and over again, on this site. There are multiple duplicates. This one is from the very inception of the site over twelve years ago.

This question is similar to: How can a Wholly Good God Deliberately Create Evil?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Your question title and question body are not asking the same single question.

If you go to this link, you will see it was closed for being a duplicate, and therein another link is provided by the Moderator who closed it showing that that other question was also a duplicate. https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/32035/if-god-is-all-knowing-then-why-didnt-he-prevent-adam-and-eve-from-sinning

I would agree that the failure of the creature was foreseeable (by Divine Wisdom) and provision was made, before the foundation of the world, to redeem and to restore to a place far beyond the first creation, for that, ever was, the Divine Purpose. You will find such expressions in both questions and answers on this site. And, therefore,  we all have to check, first, that we are not duplicating what has gone before us, in precedence. Regards.
